# I can not understanding this portion of code for this token identification program

Tags: c, for-loop, substring, c-strings, function-definition

I have got this code reference from a website and practicing with this.
When I am trying to working with `malloc()` function then how we getting the value from `right-left+2`

```
// Extraction string
char* subString(char* str, int left, int right)
{
    int i;
    char* subStr = (char*)malloc(
                  sizeof(char) * (right - left + 2));

    for (i = left; i <= right; i++)
        subStr[i - left] = str[i];
    subStr[right - left + 1] = '\0';
    return (subStr);
}

// Parsing the input STRING.
void parse(char* str)
{
    int left = 0, right = 0;
    int len = strlen(str);

    while (right <= len && left <= right) {
        if (isDelimiter(str[right]) == false)
            right++;

        if (isDelimiter(str[right]) == true && left == right) {
            if (isOperator(str[right]) == true)
                printf("'%c' IS AN OPERATOR\n", str[right]);

            right++;
            left = right;
        } else if (isDelimiter(str[right]) == true && left != right
                   || (right == len && left != right)) {
            char* subStr = subString(str, left, right - 1);

            if (isKeyword(subStr) == true)
                printf("'%s' IS A KEYWORD\n", subStr);

            left = right;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// DRIVER FUNCTION
int main()
{
     // maximum length of string is 100 here
    char str[100] = "int a = b + 1c; ";

    parse(str); // calling the parse function

    return (0);
}
```

I have got all of the concepts but this concept I am not getting this:

```
// Extracts the SUBSTRING.
char* subString(char* str, int left, int right)
{
    int i;
    char* subStr = (char*)malloc(
                  sizeof(char) * (right - left + 2));

    for (i = left; i <= right; i++)
        subStr[i - left] = str[i];
    subStr[right - left + 1] = '\0';
    return (subStr);
}
```

how the `subString` function is working. Specially `(right - left + 2)` part.
If anyone can help with any documentation or tutorial or over a comment to understand.

Comment: `right - left + 1` to calculate the number of characters in the substring (because both indices are included in the substring) + another 1 for the null terminator `'\0'`. The whole function could be safely replaced by a single `strndup(&str[left], right - left + 1)` (GNU extension)

Comment: got it but in for loop (subStr[right - left + 1] = '\0';) how this is working and where this is adding the null terminator

Comment: It's adding the null terminator at `subStr[right - left + 1]`, obviously. Try putting in concrete values for `right` and `left` and just see how it works. You can do it on paper! There is no magic theory behind expressions like `right - left + 2`, they just calculate the correct values in practice. So practice on some actual numbers and see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the code in whole is bad and it seems is written by a low-qualified programmer. You should not trust every code that you will find in the internet.

For example the function `subString` should be declared like

```
char * subString( const char *str, size_t left, size_t right );
```

instead of

```
char* subString(char* str, int left, int right);
```

That is the source string is not changed within the function. So the first parameter should have the qualifier `const`. The second and third parameters should have the unsigned integer type `size_t` (it is the type of values returned for example by the function `strlen` or by the operator `sizeof`) instead of the signed integer type `int`.

The function `subString` builds a dynamically allocated character array that will contain a substring of the passed string with the range `[left, right]`. So the length of the substring is calculated like `right - left + 1`. Also one more byte shall be reserved for the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the substring. So in whole there is required to allocate memory of the size `right - left + 2`.

In the for loop

```
for (i = left; i <= right; i++)
    subStr[i - left] = str[i];
```

the characters from the source string starting from the index `left` are copied in the dynamically allocated array starting from its position `0`.

So as the index in the for loop starts from `left` then indices in the destination array are calculated like `i - left`. That is when `i` initially equal to `left` then the expression `i - left` produces the value `0` as required for the destination array. When `i` after the first iteration of the loop will be increased by `1` then the expression `i - left` will produce the value `1` and so on.

At last this statement

```
subStr[right - left + 1] = '\0';
```

sets the last character of the destination substring equal to the terminating zero character '\0'.

Instead of the for loop you could use standard C function `memcpy` like

```
memcpy( subStr, str + left, right - left + 1 );
subStr[right - left + 1] = '\0';
```

Also the function should check whether the memory was allocated successfully before filling the allocated ,memory.

So the function could look for example the following way

```
// Extracts the SUBSTRING.
char * subString( const char *str, size_t left, size_t right )
{
    assert( left < right );

    char *subStr = malloc( right - left + 1 + sizeof( ( char )'\0' ) );

    if ( subStr != NULL )
    {
        memcpy( subStr, str + left, right - left + 1 );
        subStr[right - left + 1] = '\0';
    }

    return subStr;
}
```

A more general function can look the following way.

```
// Extracts the SUBSTRING.
char * subString( const char *str, size_t left, size_t right )
{
    char *subStr = NULL;

    if ( !( right < left ) )
    {
        size_t n = right - left + ( right != left );

        subStr = malloc( n + 1 );

        if ( subStr != NULL )
        {
            memcpy( subStr, str + left, n );
            subStr[n] = '\0';
        }
    }

    return subStr;
}
```

Comment: Speaking of a "low-qualified programmer" is a bit rude. It's better to keep with descriptions of the *code* rather than assumptions about the author of the code.

Comment: What's wrong with left == right?

Comment: @stark There is nothing wrong but in this case the function will be more complicated. Instead of allocating right - left + 2 bytes the function should allocate right - left + 1 bytes.:) Another reason is that you will need also to check that right is not less than left.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I am sorry. I have not known that there are no low qualified programmers in the world.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: there are many reasons to write suboptimal code. Very experienced developers might do it in a language they are not familiar with. And focusing on the developer doesn't really help us understand the problems or fix them. Instead, focusing on what's wrong with the *code* is the way more productive approache. This is the other side of ego-less programming.

Comment: @JoachimSauer In my opinion the productive approach is always to write a qualitative code. It indeed allows to focus on a problem and more quickly to find the reason of the problem.